# VBA code to output Poisson values is failing to execute For loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA macro that takes user input in the form of a max K value and a lambda value and then outputs to rows below the respective values of a Poisson distribution. While everything looks good to me the code isn't working and when I step through it, the For loop gets skipped completely.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pois()
    
    'Creating variables for a loop
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    'value of poisson output
    Dim p As Double
    'user input for k
    Dim k As Integer
    'user input for lambda
    Dim l As Integer
    'denominator of poisson output, starting with 1!
    Dim d As Double
    d = 1
    'Make sure the user inputted a valid value for lambda
    l = Cells(2, 2).Value
    If Not IsNumeric(l) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry" & Chr(10) & "Lambda Should Be A Number"
        End If
    If l < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry" & Chr(10) & "Lambda Should Be A Positive Number"
        End If
    k = Cells(2, 3).Value
    'Make sure the user inputted a valid value for k
    If Not IsNumeric(k) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry" & Chr(10) & "Please Enter A Positive Whole Number For k"
        End If
    If k > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry" & Chr(10) & "Please Enter A Positive Whole Number For k"
        End If
    
    For i = 1 To k
        For j = 1 To k
            d = d * j
        Next j
        p = Exp(p) * (l ^ k) / d
        Cells(i + 5, 1).Value = p
        Cells(i + 5, 2).Value = k
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Initially I thought the problem was using Integer to store factorial values that got too big but that didn't fix anything. Now I think I'm not doing the loop properly but I don't see how.

Comment: `If k > 0 Then` ... looks off btw. Shouldn't that be `<`?

Comment: Would help if you could provide some example inputs so anyone who wants to test can be sure they're using appropriate values.

Comment: What the value of `k` when you `step through it`?

Comment: It should be less than, thank you Ben. (though that did not fix the overall problem).

Comment: Some example inputs would be 3 for lambda and 10 for k.

Comment: Those values produce output for me

Comment: Yeah, I solved it. I needed k=Cells(3,2) not (2,3)... Learning vba obviously and so I just kept missing the problem. Thanks for those who helped.